# Minimally 2-connected graphs have vertex of degree 2, and $m \leq 2n - 4$

Tags: graph-theory, graph-connectivity

For the first part of the question, I know I should consider the H-path construction of 2-connected graphs. It's intuitively clear that if I try to draw these H-paths in a way that avoids vertices of degree 2, I will no longer have a minimally connected graph, but how do I make this rigorous? For the second part, the assumption is that $n \geq 4$. I'm just looking for a hint here at the moment.

Comment: I would start by clearly stating the question, and defining the symbols you use. $m$ is? $n$ is?

Comment: @PaulSinclair In graph theory $n$ (resp. $m$) are standard notations for a number of vertices (resp. edges) of a graph.